# Unity3D - Unable to properly set textures at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I use to attach textures at runtime:

```
private void ApplyTextureSet(GameObject go, TextureSet textSet)
{
    SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer = go.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    skinnedMeshRenderer.material.color = Color.white;
    
    if(textSet.albedoMap)
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_BaseMap", textSet.albedoMap);
    if (textSet.metalicMap)
    {
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.EnableKeyword ("_METALLICGLOSSMAP");
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MetallicGlossMap", textSet.metalicMap);
    }
    if (textSet.normalMap)
    {
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_NORMALMAP");
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", textSet.normalMap);
    }

    if (textSet.ambientOcullsionMap)
    {
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_OCCLUSIONMAP");
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_OcclusionMap", textSet.ambientOcullsionMap);
    }
    if (textSet.emissionMap)
    {
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
        skinnedMeshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_EmissionColor", textSet.emissionMap);
    }
}
```

This applies textures. Take a look:

[image]

Now when I click on the material. The look changes, please check this out:

[image]

As you can see on the second picture after I clicked on the material the look of the body changed. I am not sure does it change something around the Ambient Occlusion or it changes the smoothness/glossiness of the gameobject.

My question is why the look changes when I only open the material and how can I make so that in runtime it attaches the textures to the material so that once I click on the material all stays the same?